# How to generate test results in VSTS where Protractor test are running on Azure VM

Tags: azure, junit, protractor, azure-devops

I have to run the protractor test on the Azure VM. So test are running on VM and jasmine is generating the JUnit Report. However,once the test are run by VSTS the report is not getting generated as Junit report is not there in the hosted/custom agent.

So is there anyway by which we can get the report generated in VSTS but test running on VM.

Comment: You can use the rest api to send the results from azure to VSTS. It would require some additional scripting on your end but it will work. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results

Comment: How do you run protractor test? What're tasks of build definition? What's the detail code of jasmine configure file? Does it generate the report if you run test in local?

Comment: I think the issue that we need to deal with is that the selenium server needs to run in the background.  There's no "run in background" task in Azure DevOps though